# Renaming a theme so it aids SEO and the theme used is hidden

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

We are using the Divi theme for our Wordpress site, we have also activated a Child Theme that we have named our SEO keyword.

However, when you look in the "View Source" and Theme Sniffer Chrome Extensions the Divi theme is still visible.

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href="http://example.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/style.css?ver=ad89301g28d6b0c3f6d525d4e252b7a7' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/aire-valley-business-centre/style.css?ver=ad89355d28d6b0c3f6d525d4e252b7a7' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

How can i rename the Divi theme so no-one knows this theme is being used whilst still maintaining the ability to update the theme easily?

Comment: I think you are wrong. I don't think changing the name of the theme's directory to match some keyword will have any positive SEO effect. So, what you are trying to do is totally worthless.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be unable to automatically update the parent Divi theme when it's directory becomes renamed.

You can use any of caching​ plugins with `CSS minify` or/and `CSS combine` turned `ON`. This way everybody will see `/cache` directory instead of the actual theme directory.

Or as the alternative, you can update renamed parent theme manually, directory by directory, file by file.

BTW, there is no any connection between SEO and the theme name.

Comment: I have seen very effective use of a theme rename to a keyword in Google on a few occasions. If you can view the code as Google does, you can see why. Good answer above BTW

Answer (score 1):

You would have to rename the directory of the Divi theme. However, this could break the theme if there are components that depend on the directory being named Divi. Also, there may be copyright issues.